# 500 Internal Server Error when redirecting to webpage after removing file extensions from URL

Tags: html, .htaccess

To make URL navigation easier prepare some future SEO things, I removed file extensions from the URL on my online portfolio. I did this with the following code in the `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.html [L]
```

When I want to redirect from a webpage to a specific webpage on my portfolio `projecten.html`, I get an `Internal Server Error (500)` which tells me that there are too many internal redirects (maximum of 10 allowed) to this page. All other pages redirect without problems, except this page.

`projecten.html` has links to the folder `project` with three other HTML pages. All other pages on the domain redirect to pages in the root folder. There are no other files or folders that share the exact same name.

I am a designer by heart, but I have decent knowledge on front-end development. I tried looking this problem up on Google but I haven't found working solutions yet.

I hope you guys can help me :)

Comment: Can you please add how you implemented the redirection itself? THis sounds as if you are not actually redirecting, but doing an internal rewriting which certainly will lead to a rewriting loop with the code you posted.

Comment: There is an `<a>` element that redirects to `projecten`. It used to be `<a href="projecten.html"></a>` but to make the redirects working I edited it to be `<a href="projecten"></a>`. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: How is that a redirection? To me this sounds like you offer a link users can click onto so that you get a fresh request to that URL?

Comment: Nevermind that comment, I was confused with something else I tried before. I am sorry, but I think I do not understand what "redirection" means in this case. I have very few experience with editing the .htaccess for functionalities like this, so could you explain what specific redirection you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, with the help of the comments to the question, I begin to understand...

Your issue is that `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` does not change between the iterations of the rewriting process. Note that the `[L]` flag only terminates the rewriting process for the *current* iteration. But since it changes the request target another iteration is started. In that iteration the rule is applied again, since `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` did not change (it is still the same URL that got requested, whatever internal rewriting you performed.

Easiest to solve this is to use the `[END]` flag instead of the `[L]` flag *if your http server version is recent enough* (from 2.4 on). So:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.html [END]
```

But again: note that this will only work with http servers from version 2.4 on. In case of older versions (2.0 or 2.2) you will receive back an http status 500 again, but with another entry in the http servers error log.

Comment: I just tried this after some busy weeks and it works like a charm! Thanks for helping me out! :)